# Different time zones between ros nodes

Tags: ros, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Browsing the ros::now() code I've seen that it returns the local time, if I'm not mistaken it can cause some issues between computers that are on different time zones.

For instance, a robot might be on UTC, but a developer computer might be on a different time zone, wouldn't ros message timestamps be messed up and cause strange behaviour.

Shouldn't ros::timestamps be in UTC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11961/different-time-zones-between-ros-nodes/) by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-18**:
Yes, that can cause trouble for many components of Linux or Unix, not just for ROS.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-11-17**:
Hehehe, the situation is that the robot system time is UTC in order to store the logs from different robots in differents places with the same time zone. But a developer computer might be in his local time zone, and I was wondering if that could case problems.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-17**:
Your lab must be very large...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::Time::now() returns UTC. If you do a ros::Time::now().toSec(), it's going to give you the number of seconds since the Epoc (aka UTC).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-11-17**:
You are right, I missunderstood the code.